# Proper way to implement Gentelella admin template in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, gentelella, requirejs-rails

JS is not working, even **Sidebar dropdown** does not open.

After installing Gentelella, this two path have been created:

1. `app/assets/stylesheets/gentelella-custom.scss`
2. `app/assets/javascripts/gentelella-custom.js`

I have also imported it in `application.js`:

```js
import "gentelella"
import "gentelella-custom"
```

Also tried as,

```js
//= require gentelella
//= require gentelella-custom
```

Also tried it in `application.html.erb`

```xml
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>  
    
<%= javascript_include_tag 'gentelella' %>
```

But, it does not work in rails 7.